# angular 1.5 component initialize on two way binding change

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to reinitialize a component when a two way bound object changes.

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
        ng-class="{'active': activeTab.id === tab.id }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setActive(tab)"> {{ tab.title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <my-component tab="activeTab"></my-component>


app.component('myComponent', {
  template: '<div>{{ $ctrl.tab.title }}</div>',
  bindings: {
    tab: '='
  },
  controller: function() {
    var init = function() {
      console.log('hi')
    }
    init()
  }
})
```

How can I make sure `init()` is called every time activeTab.id changes?

I looked into [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) and that doesn't appear to be the answer.

[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QjHCxa0usskvfW7582Qr?p=preview) is a plunkr with code

Comment: Use $scope.$watch().

Comment: @JBNizet is there a way to do it without `$scope.$watch`? Ideally there is no `$scope` in components

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can use scope in a component: https://plnkr.co/edit/DpwlIhNLYMypcehpViP1?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `$doCheck` method of the component:

```
function myComponentController(){

  function init() {
    console.log('hi')
  }

  var previousTabId;
  this.$doCheck = function(){
    if (this.tab && previousTabId !== this.tab.id) {
      previousTabId = this.tab.id;
      init();
    }
  }.bind(this);

}

app.component('myComponent', {
  template: '<div>{{ $ctrl.tab.title }}</div>',
  bindings: {
    tab: '='
  },
  controller: [myComponentController]
})
```

Source : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

> `$doCheck()` - Called on each turn of the digest cycle. Provides an
>   opportunity to detect and act on changes. Any actions that you wish to
>   take in response to the changes that you detect must be invoked from
>   this hook; implementing this has no effect on when `$onChanges` is
>   called. For example, this hook could be useful if you wish to perform
>   a deep equality check, or to check a Date object, changes to which
>   would not be detected by AngularJS's change detector and thus not
>   trigger `$onChanges`. This hook is invoked with no arguments; if
>   detecting changes, you must store the previous value(s) for comparison
>   to the current values.

---

As far as I understand your usecase, you only need a one-way binding. And if you do, you should rather use the `$onChanges` method (which is reserved to one-way bound properties) :

> `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way bindings are updated.
>   The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound
>   properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form
>   `{ currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }`. Use this hook to
>   trigger updates within a component such as cloning the bound value to
>   prevent accidental mutation of the outer value.

And you probably should read about `$onInit`, `$onDestroy` and `$postLink` which are really useful too.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.component('myComponent', {
  template: '<div>{{ $ctrl.tab.title }}</div>',
  bindings: {
    tab: '=',
    tabChange:'&'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch(
  function() { return $scope.$ctrl.tab; },
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    init();
  }
);

var init = function() {
      console.log('hi');
    }
    init()
  }
})
```